# Javascript matching symbols in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm playing with a password validator script, and I'm doing fine with length, letters, caps, numbers and spaces.  But I'm not sure how to detect special characters.

Here's my jquery script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#password1').keyup(function() {
var pswd = $(this).val();

//validate the length
if(pswd.length < 6 ){ $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); }
//validate letter
if(pswd.match(/[A-z]/)){ $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); }
//validate capital letter
if(pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)){ $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); }
//validate number
if(pswd.match(/\d/)){ $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); }
//validate no spaces
if(pswd.match(/\s/)){ $('#spaces').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid'); }

//validate symbols
if(pswd.match(/\D/)){ $('#symbol').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid'); }

});

}); 
</script>
```

I admit I got this offline, from somewhere I cannot recall.  As I was testing the script, I noticed the Symbols were always validated whenever a letter was typed.

Is **if(pswd.match(/\D/)){** wrong?

Comment: There are problems with this script... `\D` matches any non-digit character, not just symbols.  You have two `A-Z` instead of an `A-Z` and an `a-z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\D` just means "not a digit", so any letter will work. If you want "not alphanumeric", you want `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`. Side-note, your `[A-z]` should be `[A-Za-z]` or the whole thing should be `/[a-z]/i`